# mockito and multiple HTTP in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I'm having a big problem with a project that I'm working on and I'm wondering if you could help me.

I have to perform a few unit tests using mockito, all methods go great! until you have 2 calls to http in the same method and I don't know how to differentiate them.

I have the following on the tests:

```
  // -----------------------------------------------------------services
@InjectMocks
private SandboxAccountService accountService;

@InjectMocks
private SandboxBalancesService balancesService;

@InjectMocks
private SandboxMovementsService movementService;


@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplateMovimientos;


@Test
public void test_movementsServiceImpl() throws Exception {



    //LLAMADA A LISTA DE Account

    List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    accountList.add(account);
    accountList.add(account2);

    ResponseEntity<List<Account>> list = new ResponseEntity<List<Account>>(accountList, HttpStatus.OK);


    // FIRST HTTP CALL
    when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString() , any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(list);

    //LLAMADA A LISTA DE MOVIMIENTOS

    listMovent.add(movement);
    listMovent.add(movementDos);

    ResponseEntity<List<Movement>> listaMovi = new ResponseEntity<List<Movement>>(listMovent, HttpStatus.OK);

   // Second HTTP CALL
    when(restTemplateMovimientos.exchange(anyString() , any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(listaMovi);






try {
    AccountsMovementsResponse accountsMovementsResponse = movementService.getMovements(accountsMovementsRequest,
            AUTORIZATHION_TOKEN, language);
} catch (Exception e) {

}

}
```

When debug does the lists for me correctly and all well but when he switches to the service

```
    //// This its a primary http ( Account)
    ResponseEntity<List<Account>> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(sandboxAccountURL + userId, HttpMethod.GET,entity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Account>>() {
            });

    // This list its Account CORRECT
    List<Account> lista=exchange.getBody();


   // code.....

    // This its a second http ( movement )
    ResponseEntity<List<Movement>> movementList = restTemplate.exchange(GenerateUrl, HttpMethod.GET,entity,
                            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Movement>>() {
                            });
                 // This list should be moves, but it's a list of accounts.
                 List<Movement> listMovement= movementList.getBody();
```

My big problem is that instead of having 2 different lists I have 2 lists of them so the test can't continue.

if i try the code everything works without a problem and makes it work, the problem i have is that at the moment of testing it clones the lists.

I don't know if there is a way to make the mock's "when" can make them different because it makes me understand that it takes the first when I do.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, instead of using the key several times using the when you can make a single call and then making several returns in the order that you require attached the answer of how I work

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class),
            any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(list).thenReturn(listaMovi);
```